# Делаю программу на с++. Вылезает ошибка

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Пишу прогу, ***вылезает ошибка, что отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора cars::cars, соответствующие  списку аргументов***. Делал всё по аналогичному коду.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

class cars
{
private:
    int m_nds=((m_cena/100)*15);
    int m_cena;
    int m_nishtyaki;
public:
    cars(int cena,int nishtyaki )
    {
        cena = m_cena;
        nishtyaki = m_nishtyaki;
    }

    int get_m_cena() const
    {
       return m_cena ;
    }

    friend cars operator+(const cars &cena, const cars &nishtyaki);
};

cars operator+(const cars &cena, const cars &nishtyaki)
{
    return cars(cena.m_cena + nishtyaki.m_nishtyaki+cena.m_nds);
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Введите ценник на BMW" << endl;
    int cennik_bmw;
    cin >> cennik_bmw;
    cout << "Введите ценник на Mercedes" << endl;
    int cennik_benza;
    cin >> cennik_benza;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cars benz(cennik_benza,1000);
    cars bmw(cennik_bmw,1000);
    cars summa = benz + bmw;
    cout <<"Вы должны за машины "<< summa.get_m_cena()<<" долларов" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В `operator+` вызывается конструктор с одним аргументом, которого у вас не существует.

Comment: Сообщение компилятора стоит читать полностью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите - у вас есть два странных места:

Первое -

```
int get_m_cena() const
{
   return ;
}
```

Вы же обязались вернуть `int` - так почему не возвращаете? :) наверное, тут должно быть `return m_cena;`?

А второе - вот:

```
cars operator+(const cars &cena, const cars &nishtyaki)
{
    return cars(cena.m_cena + nishtyaki.m_nishtyaki+cena.m_nds);
}
```

Вы вроде бы возвращаете некий `cars` (логику сложения автомобилей оставим на другой вопрос...) - но передаете ему *только одно значение* -

```
cena.m_cena + nishtyaki.m_nishtyaki+cena.m_nds
```

В то время как для создания автомобиля вы обязаны передать **ДВА** параметра:

```
cars(int cena,int nishtyaki )
```

другого конструктора, с одним параметром, у вас нет.

Так что решите, какой `cars` должен возвращаться, с какими **двумя** параметрами - и все получится.

Ну, как получится... Скомпилируется. А как будет работать - это второй вопрос, на это я не пытался смотреть - для этого надо знать, что программа *должна* делать.

Comment: С get_m_cena там вроде все нормально, а зачем вместо одного комментария писать полотно на целый экран - непонятно.

Comment: @user7860670 Судя по коду, человеку надо разжевать детали. В чем состоит ошибка, ему сообщил компилятор, а вот понять смысл сказанного компилятором у него не получается. Боюсь, простого комментария - повтора сообщения компилятора - ему не хватит. И вообще - ну вот нашло на меня такое настроение, что я захотел написать ответ, а не краткий комментарий - это недостаточная причина? :)

Comment: @Harry спасибо Вам,что ответили на мой вопрос,НО я либо тупой,либо еще что,но хоть убейте я не понял,Вы пишите: Вы вроде бы возвращаете некий cars -но передаете ему только одно значение -

cena.m_cena + nishtyaki.m_nishtyaki+cena.m_nds

В то время как для создания автомобиля вы обязаны передать ДВА параметра, КАКИЕ ДВА ПАРАМЕТРА И ГДЕ ОДИН ПАРАМЕТР?Помогите глупому студенту...

Comment: Еще раз - вы не можете создать `cars` иначе как указав цену и ништяки, что бы это не значило. **ДВА** параметра - цена и ништяки. Когда вы складываете два `cars`, то возвращаете `cars`, которому передаете один параметр (одно значение, одно число - не знаю, как вам понятнее): `cena.m_cena + nishtyaki.m_nishtyaki+cena.m_nds` Не знаю, если это цена - то вы не указали ништяки, если ништяки - то не указали цену. Так понятнее?

Comment: @Harry , спасибо Вам большое...

Comment: Если ответ устраивает - можете его принять (птичка слева)...